Apache Ignite JDBC (potentially ODBC & thin client) disable setting doesn't prevent JDBC connections or querying
In order to disable access through JDBC/ODBC/thin client, as mentioned in the docs, I had configured IgniteConfiguration#clientConnectorConfiguration to set odbcEnabled, jdbcEnabled and thinClientEnabled to false.
<property name="clientConnectorConfiguration">
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.ClientConnectorConfiguration">
    <!-- Disabling all three.. -->
    <property name="jdbcEnabled" value="false"/>
    <property name="odbcEnabled" value="false"/>
    <property name="thinClientEnabled" value="false"/>
</bean>
</property>

However when I tried verifying this with a simple JDBC test program (please see below) I was able to successfully connect & execute queries despite JDBC being disabled...
Is this a bug? Does anyone know what else needs to be done to disable these?
IgniteReachabilityChecker.java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver;

public class IgniteReachabilityChecker {
    private static final String IGNITE_QUERY = "SELECT count(1) FROM TEST.USER";
    private static final String IGNITE_URL = "jdbc:ignite:thin://%s";

    public static void main(String...arg) {
        if (arg == null || arg.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Please specify server IP");
            return;
        }
        String igniteJdbcConnectUrl = String.format(IGNITE_URL, arg[0]);
        System.out.println("The Ignite jdbc connect url is " + igniteJdbcConnectUrl);
        boolean isReachable = false;
        try (
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(igniteJdbcConnectUrl);
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(IGNITE_QUERY)
                ) {
            isReachable = rs.next();
            System.out.println("Test query result is " + rs.getInt(1));
        } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
            System.out.println("Got SQL Exception reaching ignite-grid-node. Exception is : " + sqlException);
        }
        System.out.println("Is ignite-grid-node reachable (t/f) : " + isReachable);
    }
}

UPDATE (24-MAY-24):
One additional info is that my setup has one Ignite server node & several Ignite thick client nodes. The setting is applied to the config of only the server node.
Below is the Ignite server node log snippet where I see the settings being picked up,
[0.011s][info][gc] Using G1
[1.220s][info][gc] GC(0) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (Metadata GC Threshold) 40M->7M(1792M) 6.025ms
[1.220s][info][gc] GC(1) Concurrent Mark Cycle
[1.224s][info][gc] GC(1) Pause Remark 8M->8M(1792M) 1.657ms
[1.224s][info][gc] GC(1) Pause Cleanup 8M->8M(1792M) 0.018ms
[1.226s][info][gc] GC(1) Concurrent Mark Cycle 5.508ms
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.167  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal - 

>>>    __________  ________________  
>>>   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/  
>>>  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/    
>>> /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/   
>>> 
>>> ver. 8.8.39#20240403-sha1:a6d7ac2a
>>> 2024 Copyright(C) GridGain Systems, Inc. and Contributors
>>> 
>>> GridGain documentation: http://gridgain.com/docs/index.html

10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.173  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal - Config URL: file:/opt/ignite/gridgain-community-8.8.39/conf/default-config.xml
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.195  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal - IgniteConfiguration [igniteInstanceName=null, pubPoolSize=16, svcPoolSize=16, callbackPoolSize=16, stripedPoolSize=16, sysPoolSize=16, mgmtPoolSize=4, dataStreamerPoolSize=16, utilityCachePoolSize=16, utilityCacheKeepAliveTime=60000, p2pPoolSize=2, qryPoolSize=16, buildIdxPoolSize=4, igniteHome=/opt/ignite/gridgain-community-8.8.39, igniteWorkDir=/opt/ignite/gridgain-community-8.8.39/work, mbeanSrv=com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@2f666ebb, nodeId=65d47611-74a8-4485-b963-7b01f4481b29, marsh=BinaryMarshaller [], marshLocJobs=false, daemon=false, p2pEnabled=true, netTimeout=5000, netCompressionLevel=1, sndRetryDelay=1000, sndRetryCnt=3, metricsHistSize=10000, metricsUpdateFreq=2000, metricsExpTime=9223372036854775807, discoSpi=TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=0, ackTimeout=0, marsh=null, reconCnt=10, reconDelay=2000, maxAckTimeout=600000, soLinger=5, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=true, internalLsnr=null, skipAddrsRandomization=false], segPlc=STOP, segResolveAttempts=2, waitForSegOnStart=true, allResolversPassReq=true, segChkFreq=10000, commSpi=TcpCommunicationSpi [connectGate=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.ConnectGateway@14fc5d40, ctxInitLatch=java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@51e0301d[Count = 1], stopping=false, clientPool=null, nioSrvWrapper=null, stateProvider=null, connectionRequestor=null], evtSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.eventstorage.NoopEventStorageSpi@47d7bfb3, colSpi=NoopCollisionSpi [], deploySpi=LocalDeploymentSpi [], indexingSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.indexing.noop.NoopIndexingSpi@3afae281, addrRslvr=null, encryptionSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.encryption.noop.NoopEncryptionSpi@26ae880a, tracingSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.tracing.NoopTracingSpi@260f2144, clientMode=false, rebalanceThreadPoolSize=4, rebalanceTimeout=10000, rebalanceBatchesPrefetchCnt=2, rebalanceThrottle=0, rebalanceBatchSize=524288, txCfg=TransactionConfiguration [txSerEnabled=false, dfltIsolation=REPEATABLE_READ, dfltConcurrency=PESSIMISTIC, dfltTxTimeout=300000, txTimeoutOnPartitionMapExchange=300000, deadlockTimeout=10000, pessimisticTxLogSize=0, pessimisticTxLogLinger=10000, tmLookupClsName=null, txManagerFactory=null, useJtaSync=false], cacheSanityCheckEnabled=true, discoStartupDelay=60000, deployMode=SHARED, p2pMissedCacheSize=100, locHost=10.173.120.39, timeSrvPortBase=31100, timeSrvPortRange=100, failureDetectionTimeout=210000, sysWorkerBlockedTimeout=120000, clientFailureDetectionTimeout=210000, metricsLogFreq=60000, connectorCfg=ConnectorConfiguration [jettyPath=null, host=null, port=11211, noDelay=true, directBuf=false, sndBufSize=32768, rcvBufSize=32768, idleQryCurTimeout=600000, idleQryCurCheckFreq=60000, sndQueueLimit=0, selectorCnt=4, idleTimeout=7000, sslEnabled=false, sslClientAuth=false, sslCtxFactory=null, sslFactory=null, portRange=100, threadPoolSize=16, msgInterceptor=null], odbcCfg=null, warmupClos=null, atomicCfg=AtomicConfiguration [seqReserveSize=1000, cacheMode=PARTITIONED, backups=1, aff=null, grpName=null], classLdr=null, sslCtxFactory=null, platformCfg=null, binaryCfg=null, memCfg=MemoryConfiguration [sysCacheInitSize=41943040, sysCacheMaxSize=104857600, pageSize=0, concLvl=0, dfltMemPlcName=default, dfltMemPlcSize=4294967296], pstCfg=null, dsCfg=DataStorageConfiguration [sysRegionInitSize=41943040, sysRegionMaxSize=104857600, pageSize=0, concLvl=0, dfltDataRegConf=DataRegionConfiguration [name=default, maxSize=4294967296, initSize=268435456, swapPath=null, pageEvictionMode=DISABLED, pageReplacementMode=CLOCK, evictionThreshold=0.9, emptyPagesPoolSize=100, metricsEnabled=false, metricsSubIntervalCount=5, metricsRateTimeInterval=60000, persistenceEnabled=false, checkpointPageBufSize=0, lazyMemoryAllocation=true, warmUpCfg=null, memoryAllocator=null], dataRegions=null, storagePath=null, checkpointFreq=180000, lockWaitTime=10000, checkpointThreads=4, checkpointWriteOrder=SEQUENTIAL, walHistSize=20, maxWalArchiveSize=1073741824, walSegments=10, walSegmentSize=67108864, walPath=db/wal, walArchivePath=db/wal/archive, metricsEnabled=false, walMode=LOG_ONLY, walTlbSize=131072, walBuffSize=0, walFlushFreq=2000, walFsyncDelay=1000, walRecordIterBuffSize=67108864, alwaysWriteFullPages=false, fileIOFactory=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.AsyncFileIOFactory@48b22fd4, metricsSubIntervalCnt=5, metricsRateTimeInterval=60000, walAutoArchiveAfterInactivity=-1, writeThrottlingEnabled=false, walCompactionEnabled=false, walCompactionLevel=1, checkpointReadLockTimeout=null, walPageCompression=DISABLED, walPageCompressionLevel=null, dfltWarmUpCfg=null, encCfg=org.apache.ignite.configuration.EncryptionConfiguration@3b08f438, defragmentationThreadPoolSize=4, minWalArchiveSize=-1, memoryAllocator=null], activeOnStart=null, autoActivation=null, clusterStateOnStart=null, sqlConnCfg=null, cliConnCfg=ClientConnectorConfiguration [host=null, port=10800, portRange=100, sockSndBufSize=262144, sockRcvBufSize=262144, tcpNoDelay=true, maxOpenCursorsPerConn=128, threadPoolSize=16, selectorCnt=8, idleTimeout=0, handshakeTimeout=10000, **jdbcEnabled=false, odbcEnabled=false, thinCliEnabled=false,** sslEnabled=false, useIgniteSslCtxFactory=true, sslClientAuth=false, sslCtxFactory=null, thinCliCfg=ThinClientConfiguration [maxActiveTxPerConn=100, maxActiveComputeTasksPerConn=0, sendServerExcStackTraceToClient=false]], mvccVacuumThreadCnt=2, mvccVacuumFreq=5000, authEnabled=false, failureHnd=null, commFailureRslvr=null, sqlCfg=SqlConfiguration [longQryWarnTimeout=1000, sqlQryHistSize=1000, sqlGlobalMemoryQuota=60%, sqlQueryMemoryQuota=0, sqlOffloadingEnabled=true, dfltQryTimeout=0], asyncContinuationExecutor=null]
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.195  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal - Daemon mode: off
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.195  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal - OS: Linux 4.18.0-477.21.1.el8_8.x86_64 amd64
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.196  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal - OS user: sannavmgr
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.198  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal - PID: 55
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.199  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal - Language runtime: Java Platform API Specification ver. 17
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.199  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal - VM information: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 17.0.9+9 Eclipse Adoptium OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.9+9
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.201  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal - VM total memory: 1.8GB
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.201  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal - Remote Management [restart: on, REST: on, JMX (remote: off)]
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.202  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal - Logger: Log4J2Logger [quiet=false, config=/conf/log4j2.xml]
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.202  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal - System cache's DataRegion size is configured to 40 MB. Use DataStorageConfiguration.systemRegionInitialSize property to change the setting.
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.203  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal - Configured caches [in 'sysMemPlc' dataRegion: ['ignite-sys-cache']]
10.173.120.39 - [WARN ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.203  WARN [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal - Peer class loading is enabled (disable it in production for performance and deployment consistency reasons)
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.204  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal - 3-rd party licenses can be found at: /opt/ignite/gridgain-community-8.8.39/libs/licenses
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.204  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal - Local node user attribute [ROLE=OBJECT_MANAGER]
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.283  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.plugin.IgnitePluginProcessor - Configured plugins:
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.284  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.plugin.IgnitePluginProcessor -   ^-- None
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.284  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.plugin.IgnitePluginProcessor - 
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.285  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.failure.FailureProcessor - Configured failure handler: [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]]]
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.579  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi - Successfully bound communication NIO server to TCP port [port=47109, locHost=/10.173.120.39, selectorsCnt=8, selectorSpins=0, pairedConn=false]
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.626  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.collision.GridCollisionManager - Collision resolution is disabled (all jobs will be activated upon arrival).
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.629  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal - Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
[2.377s][info][gc] GC(2) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (Metadata GC Threshold) 80M->13M(1792M) 9.136ms
[2.378s][info][gc] GC(3) Concurrent Mark Cycle
[2.384s][info][gc] GC(3) Pause Remark 14M->14M(1792M) 3.556ms
[2.388s][info][gc] GC(3) Pause Cleanup 14M->14M(1792M) 0.235ms
[2.393s][info][gc] GC(3) Concurrent Mark Cycle 15.004ms
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.849  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi - Successfully bound to TCP port [port=47500, localHost=edavbd001034-01/10.173.120.39, locNodeId=65d47611-74a8-4485-b963-7b01f4481b29]
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.851  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.filename.PdsFoldersResolver - Consistent ID used for local node is [10.173.120.39:47500] according to persistence data storage folders
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.896  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager - Configured data regions initialized successfully [total=4]
10.173.120.39 - [WARN ] 2024-05-20 16:15:32.982  WARN [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing - Serialization of Java objects in H2 was enabled.
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:33.205  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.QueryMemoryManager - SQL query global quota was set to 1127428915. Current memory tracking parameters: [qryQuota=0, globalQuota=1127428915, offloadingEnabled=true]
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:33.206  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.QueryMemoryManager - SQL query memory quota was set to 0. Current memory tracking parameters: [qryQuota=0, globalQuota=1127428915, offloadingEnabled=true]
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:33.256  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerProcessor - Client connector processor has started on TCP port 10809
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:33.304  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.tcp.GridTcpRestProtocol - Command protocol successfully started [name=TCP binary, host=/10.173.120.39, port=11211]
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:33.327  INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @2965ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:33.508  INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.4.53.v20231009; built: 2023-10-09T12:29:09.265Z; git: 27bde00a0b95a1d5bbee0eae7984f891d2d0f8c9; jvm 17.0.9+9
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:33.537  INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@706f6d26{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{10.173.120.39:8080}
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:33.538  INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @3176ms
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:33.538  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.http.jetty.GridJettyRestProtocol - Command protocol successfully started [name=Jetty REST, host=/10.173.120.39, port=8080]
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:33.590  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal - Non-loopback local IPs: 10.173.120.39, 172.17.0.1, 172.18.0.1
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:33.590  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal - Enabled local MACs: 02424F676409, 02426348D4EE, FA163E51C5B2
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:33.608  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.cluster.IgniteClusterImpl - Shutdown policy was updated [oldVal=null, newVal=null]
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:33.609  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.stat.IgniteStatisticsManagerImpl - Statistics usage state was changed from null to null
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:33.622  INFO [main] org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi - Connection check threshold is calculated: 210000
10.173.120.39 - [INFO ] 2024-05-20 16:15:33.669  INFO [tcp-disco-srvr-[:47500]-#3-#69] org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi - TCP discovery accepted incoming connection...


I can't reproduce the problem. The following code throws a JDBC connection is not allowed exception
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration()
        .setClientConnectorConfiguration(new ClientConnectorConfiguration()
        .setJdbcEnabled(false)
        .setOdbcEnabled(true)
        .setThinClientEnabled(true));

Ignition.start(cfg);

String connStr = "jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1:10800";

try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connStr)) {
    conn.setSchema(CACHE_NAME);

    try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT 1");
        rs.next();
    }
}

Make sure the config file is loaded correctly by Ignite.

Thank you for your response. That's strange I did verify that in the server node log on startup.

One additional info is that my setup has one Ignite server node & several Ignite thick client nodes. The setting is applied to the config of only the server node.

Thick clients might be able to accept JDBC connections too, make sure to apply this setting to all nodes.

Thanks @Pavel Tupitsyn that's what I suspected & added that note. I haven't yet verified it & will do today...but given that your testing with only server node works most likely that's what going on. In my opinion, this should be a bug. Either we should enforce this setting only on server nodes or we should clearly document that these need to be set for server & client (thick client aswell?) nodes and validate for and fail a server or client nodes when this setting conflicts with the running grid config so we fail fast.

Heard from Gridgain that the setting is not required to be set on clients (thick or otherwise). I shared my observation & they are investigating..one issue they have already observed was if two server nodes are there & if one has it not disabled then also this can happen which is again a separate bug..
